# How do I display different error messages for different validation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling

I have a field for taking user's mobile number and as no one wants unwanted stuff in a particular field, I added validations.
Here is the code of my validations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :user_name, uniqueness: true
  validates :mobile,
                  length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 10, :message => "Just those 10 digits, thanks for the extra"},
                  :numericality => {:only_integer => true, :message => "So your number has alphabets in it?"}
end
```

The validations I added were of the length and numericality, now when I input a number shorter or longer than 10 it displays the first error but when I add some alphabets it still displays the error for length.

Also I checked, even if I am entering 10 digits in the mobile field I am still shown the error of length. Maybe there is also some problem with the validations I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Please, clarify what is exact question?
Your validations are correct.

Consider my code:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActsAsCommentable::Comment
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
    validates :title,
                    length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 10, :message => "Just those 10 digits, thanks for the extra"},
                    :numericality => {:only_integer => true, :message => "So your number has alphabets in it?"}
end
```

And output in console:

```
comment = Comment.new
comment.title = "Long text content"
comment.valid? # false
comment.errors 
# {
#     :title => [
#         [0] "Just those 10 digits, thanks for the extra",
#         [1] "So your number has alphabets in it?"
#     ]
# }
```

Both error messages are present.

Comment: The problem is that when I enter more than ten characters it shows the error for length,

Also when I enter a alphabet in it, it displays the same error (of length) instead of the error of numercality

Comment: Does my example works as you want?
So, you mean, if you enter alphabet symbols AND more than 10 it displays length error but not display numericality error?
How do you try it? Maybe after you change code in model, you do not `reload!` or call `valid?` or using the same object etc?
Please, post some code example with what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: No it doesn't. First I added a long string of numbers and it showed the string error then I tried 9 numbers and one letter and then also it showed length error. Also when I tried the correct input, ten digits then also it displayed the same error.

Comment: After each time you change your mobile attribute, and before checking errors hash, do you call `valid?` on object ? Without it, you wont see any re-validations

Comment: No, I don't think so. Can you show me a sample code on how to call it on user creation.